# Warning with apache.commons.digester jar in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, rss

I am struggling with a warning in my android project when i use jsf-impl.jar for parsing rss feed.
This is the warning i get:

```
Dxwarning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (com.sun.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class
```

If i use this jar in a normal java class, not one that extends Activity from Android i dont get any errors or warnings. I tried cleaning the project, refresh, restart eclipse, computer. I have no idea what to do. Tried with other jars but i don't find the jars that i need to import in my class:

> import com.sun.org.apache.commons.digester.rss.Channel;
>   import com.sun.org.apache.commons.digester.rss.Item;
>   import com.sun.org.apache.commons.digester.rss.RSSDigester;

Does someone have an idea to what to do? And yes, i am googling loads...
Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the warning is about the compiler, I am interested to know who the jar was built? If it was downloaded as is, then I would try building the Jar file myself, with JDK 6.

Comment: I donwloaded the jar from here: [link](http://www.findjar.com/jar/javax/faces/jsf-impl/1.2-b19/jsf-impl-1.2-b19.jar.html) . To build the jar again, i need the sources, right? thx

Comment: Yes, you can get the source from here.http://download.java.net/maven/1/javax.faces/java-sources/